# Hard Drive Partitioning?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

I am not a basic user of computers, but frankly I have never done a partition of a hard drive. But I decided to shrink the only HD in the computer by 25GB for Ubuntu, however I realized that Ubuntu will partition the HD. However, I am stuck with a 25GB partition that I can not use, at least I think so... Can I use the partition when installing Ubuntu (version 9.10) or can I make the partition apart of the rest of the drive again? When I try to delete it, Windows 7 (the only OS at the moment) prompts me stating that it is an extended partition and will be inaccessible if I do so.

Help?

Comment: Are you sure that you want to be using 9.10? That version is becoming fast obsolete. The latest version is 10.10. It's a very different operating system from that old version.

Answer (score 1):

Have a read through the community documentation [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DualBoot/WindowsFirst), if the empty partition is formatted as NTFS you will need to change it to ext3 or ext4 to install Ubuntu on.

The Win7 partition should be clearly labelled as such when you open GParted to view your hard drive and if you do not select it for formatting it will remain untouched by the installation of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this partition for ubuntu. When you install it from the liveCD select 'advanced partitioning options' (or something with advanced in it :)) and map the partition to /.